# border radius the bottom of a dropdown menu only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

working on a simple nav bar. so far its working perfectly for me minus one minor detail. when it drops down i want the middle sections to remain a rectangle and the bottom section to always be curvy on the bottom. right now I have it so the bottom section is curvy, though when I hover over it the regular rectangle shows back up. I tried to fix it myself, but all I could get to work was it would change all sections to curvy

here is a jsFiddle of what I am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/7mjEC/

and here is the css:

```
 @charset "utf-8";
#topMenu {
    padding: 0px;
    width: 760px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
}
#topMenu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#topMenu ul li {
    background-color: #666;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#topMenu ul li a {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
}
#topMenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 31px;
}
#topMenu ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #39F;
}
#topMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
#topMenu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #919191;
}
#topMenu .topleftmenuitem {
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
#topMenu .toprightmenuitem {
    border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
#topMenu .topleftmenuitem:hover {
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 0;
}
and #topMenu .toprightmenuitem:hover {
    border-radius: 0 20px 0 0;
}
#topMenu ul ul li:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```

see when **you hover over the last child** it turns from *curved* to *rectangle*, I just want to keep it always curved.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-of-type) or [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3alast-child) pseudo

```
#topMenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-of-type a:hover {
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
    background: #f00; /* You can remove this, its just for a demo */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7mjEC/1/)

---

The above selector means, select direct child `ul` to element having an `id` of `#topMenu`, than select direct `li` to that `ul`, moving further applies the same and at the end, we select the last `li` child which is nested under level 2 `ul` and we apply the styles on `a:hover`

Comment: Good job Saint Alien. ;)

Comment: @Ruddy haha come on, not you please :)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle. You DO NOT need to break all of the ul's up like this. Please see my Fiddle for much simpler code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7mjEC/2/

The only css change you really need is to add ONE selector in:

```
ul ul li:last-child,
ul ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
}
```